# What is big in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am thinking of writing a python script with a 400,000 items dictionary.

Is that dumb?

How big is too big?

(My data is in a database. The plan was to search the dictionary every time I run the program with an infile list. Like a query.)

Answer (score 4):

Best way to be sure: write a 3 line script to test it.

It's probably too big for a machine with 128 MB running Unix. It's probably unnoticeable on a monster with 24 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. Might be the only way, might be completely inappropriate given the problem at hand.

A better question would be to explain to us your problem and how you're thinking of approaching it (why do you need that dict?).

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionary is implemented as [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), thus has access cost of *O(1)*.

As long as you have enough memory for this, this won't be a problem and it will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

On a 64-bit machine I ran the following script...

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in xrange(400000):
...     d[i] = i*2
```

This caused the Python process to use about 75MB more memory, working out to around 200 bytes per entry in the dictionary.

If you're storing larger objects then your memory usage will be higher, but if you're just using integers then 400000 is not much.

Answer (score 1):

On a 64bit Linux system using simple `object`s to populate a dict with 400000 items:

```
>>> d = dict((object(), object()) for _ in range(400000))
>>> d.__sizeof__()
25166072
```

This means the `dict` will cost about 25MB. Prior to creating this, my Python instance had 8MB resident memory, and afterwards, 44MB.

Certainly within acceptable bounds for modern machines.